# Was ist ein Kurzsack?

Tags: meaning, regional

Bei der Bearbeitung einer [Frage](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/72772) auf einer anderen Stackexchange-Seite [traf ich](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/g/genpub/acd0698.0003.004/23?page=root;rgn=full+text;size=100;view=image) auf folgendes Wort:

> Wenn ein Mädchen den Burschen gefallen und beim Tanze das erste sein will, da muss es an einem Sonntage im Fasching mit seiner Mutter, in Sonntagskleidern angethan, in's Feld gehen und im **Kurzsack** Brot, Salz und Brantwein mitnehmen und eine Tollkirschwurzel ausgraben und dann an ihre Stelle die mitgebrachten Sachen zurücklassen.

Aus dem Kontext wird zwar einigermaßen klar, dass es um irgendeine Form von Beutel geht, aber nicht, ob eine spezifische Form oder Art des Tragens gemeint ist. Geht es um einen Umhängebeutel, eine Art Rucksack, eine Handtasche, ein am Gürtel getragener Beutel, ...?

Der Schreiber des Textes, [Dimitrie Dan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimitrie_Dan), war ein rumänischer Priester und Historiker, der auf deutsch für die *Zeitschrift für österreichische Volkskunde* eine Serie über den Volksglauben der Rumänen in der Bukovina schrieb. Erschienen ist der Text 1897. Laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bukowina#Bev%C3%B6lkerung) bekannten sich 1910 22 % der Bevölkerung der Bukovina zur deutschen Umgangssprache. Der Autor war mit dem Deutschen zwar hauptsächlich als Wissenschafts- und Verwaltungssprache vertraut, erlebte sie also aber auch in seiner Alltagsumgebung.

In keinem der einschlägigen Nachschlagewerke (DWDS, BDO, WBÖ) bin ich auf den Begriff "Kurzsack" gestoßen. Ist er irgendwem bekannt?

Comment: Das selbe Dokument beschreibt auch: "Zur Leinsaat selbst nimmt man gewöhnlich einen recht langen Sack (oder ein Bett- oder Tischtuch) und lässt den Saamen recht langsam in diesen hineinlaufen." - Das klingt, als ob es einfach für verschiedene Zwecke unterschiedlich lange/große Säcke gab. Um Brot, Salz und Brantwein zu transportieren, ist ein kurzer (kleiner) Sack ausreichend gewesen.

Answer (score 1):

Anscheinend bezieht es sich darauf, dass der für den Bauern oder Handwerker übliche Sack für Heu, Kartoffeln, Holz etc. wesentlich zu groß zum Tragen einer Picknickmalzeit ist. Vor hundert Jahren hat es noch keine Gewerkschaften gegeben, die die tragbare Last auf 30 kg heruntergedrückt haben, und der Zentnersack für Kartoffeln war eine Art Norm noch vor 50 Jahren. Diese Säcke hatten auch wohl auch keine Tragegurte. M.a.W. vermute ich hier kleine Rucksäcke mit Gurt, wie man sie in Bildern von Wanderburschen des 19 Jahrhunderts sieht, manchmal auch mit einem Stock über den Schultern getragen.